# query a related table in self rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have the following relationship:

```
class User 
  has_many :followed_users, :through => :relationships, source: :followed
```

When I say `User.last.followed_users` in the console, this works. However, when I create a method in the `User` class that uses `self.followed_users` this fails. I want to be able to call `followed_users` within the model that implements it. Any help?

Error message says that the method `followed_users` doesn't exist.

Comment: What error message are you getting?  Can you show the code for the method that is erroring?

Answer (score 0):

How to define a follower/following set of relationships:

```
class User
  has_many :followings
  has_many :followers, :through => :followings
  has_many :inverse_followings, :class_name => "Following", :foreign_key => "follower_id"
  has_many :followed_users, :through => :inverse_followings, :source => :user
end
```

Make sure you have a Following class (or Relationship class for your example) that has a user_id and a follower_id to express this relationship.

Calling `self.followed_users` or `self.followers` within a User class method should work fine.